# How to add a year to the existing date list without erasing any of the existing ones

Tags: r

I have a data frame with Date and Velocity as they are seen below. My issue is that some years are missing like 1945 and 1951.

I would like to add 1945 to Date only once and on the position that it should be on between 1944 and 1946. I know some years are repeated. The day and month are not very important as they are more of a position holder. I plan to make the velocity equal to 0 for all the added years (e.g. mm-dd-1945)

What I have

```
    Date         Velocity
    2/23/1944    1 
    12/26/1944   2
    1/7/1946     5
    3/25/1947    8
    4/14/1948    10
    6/18/1949    12
    1/31/1950    13
    12/7/1950    14 
    1/27/1952    15
```

I tried doing the following

```
    NewYear <- complete(Data,Date = seq.Date(min(Data$Date),
    max(Data$Date), by="year"))
```

but all of the existing dates get overwritten and I end up with this

```
    Date         Velocity
    2/23/1944    NA
    2/23/1945    NA
    2/23/1946    NA
    2/23/1947    NA
    2/23/1948    NA
    2/23/1949    NA
    2/23/1950    NA
    2/23/1951    NA
    2/23/1952    NA
```

Desired Output

```
    Date         Velocity
    2/23/1944    1 
    12/26/1944   2
    1/01/1945    0
    1/7/1946     5
    3/25/1947    8
    4/14/1948    10
    6/18/1949    12
    1/31/1950    13
    12/7/1950    14
    1/1/1951     0
    1/27/1952    15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to extract the year from the date then use `complete` to get missing years and replace the missing `Date` with first day of the `Year`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), 
         Year = as.integer(format(Date, "%Y"))) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year)), fill = list(Velocity = 0)) %>%
  mutate(Date = if_else(is.na(Date), as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01-01")), Date))



#    Year Date       Velocity
#   <int> <date>        <dbl>
# 1  1944 1944-02-23        1
# 2  1944 1944-12-26        2
# 3  1945 1945-01-01        0
# 4  1946 1946-01-07        5
# 5  1947 1947-03-25        8
# 6  1948 1948-04-14       10
# 7  1949 1949-06-18       12
# 8  1950 1950-01-31       13
# 9  1950 1950-12-07       14
#10  1951 1951-01-01        0
#11  1952 1952-01-27       15
```

Add `select(-Year)` if you don't want `Year` column in your final output.